# iPad - "user rights" app

Tags: ios, ipad-app, children

I have an iPad and am looking for an app that allows me to control who may open / delete what apps.

Background: I have a child. I play some games on the iPad and it "happens" that she deletes them. Also there are games I put effort into and don't want her to stop them from working ("Tomorrow I have the 6.000.000 gold I need" - "You used all my gold to buy flowers? That took me weeks!")
She should be able to play / delete her own apps though.

So I want to be able to have an access control on the iPad the regular settings don't allow this fine granularity.

Possible solutions could be "have user accounts" or "have passwords on the apps" or the like.

Of course the controlling app itself must be protectable.

My iPad is not rooted/jailbraked and I would prefer keeping it that way but if you have a working solution that requires rooting I would be interested in it as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not possible without jailbreaking (or 'rooting' as you have referred to) since there are a number of restrictions present on iOS (and the App Store) that such an app would break. However, iOS does come with built-in Restrictions in Settings that allow you to passcode-prevent features such as deleting apps.

For more information on Restrictions and to see exactly what you can protect, see this Apple KB article:

- [iOS: Understanding Restrictions (parental controls)](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213)

---

If you jailbreak, I recommend [**iAppLock**](http://iapplock.thinkyeah.com):

> iAppLock is an iOS app to protect your privacy in iPhone and iPad.
>
> Lock your Messages, Mail, Photos, Contacts, Facebook and any apps you like.

[image]

This tweak works very well at protecting apps and it fits very well with the iOS 7 style.

I used to use it, but now I use BioLockdown (which is similar but uses the iPhone 5s Touch ID — not applicable to the iPad). It worked very well.

Comment: Thank you, do you use iAppLock? What are your experiences?

Comment: @Angelo I used to use it, but now I use BioLockdown (which is similar but uses the iPhone 5s Touch ID). It worked very well.

Comment: Could you add that experience and your reasons for the switch to the answer? The more details you add the more this answer changes from "This can do it [link]" to a real recommendation "You should use this because [reason]"

Comment: @Angelo Edited. BioLockdown doesn't really apply to iPad as it is intended for Touch ID.